# How to create an array of objects from API response in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github-api

I am following [this tutorial](https://revs.runtime-revolution.com/integrating-a-third-party-api-with-rails-5-134f960ddbba) to connect to GitHub API. I can successfully connect and bring back the currently authenticated user information.

However I am trying to get back the user's repos, the response is an array of objects.

I do not know how to pass that to the view. From the tutorial I am following, take a look at the `recipe.rb` class [here](https://github.com/AnnieLee/blog-spoonacular-api/blob/master/app/services/spoonacular/recipe.rb).

`attr_accessor :ingrediets` will function as an array (line 8). In line 32 she is passing the response from an API to a custom method to parse it, create an `Ingredient` object and push it into the array. `self.ingredients = parse_ingredients(args)`

This is the custom method

```
def parse_ingredients(args = {})
  args.fetch("extendedIngredients", []).map { |ingredient| Ingredient.new(ingredient) }
end
```

As you can see, from the `args` object she is *fetching* the `extendedIngredients` property in the response and creating the array.

My problem is that with the GitHub API, the response is a plain array and my attempt to parse it and turn it into an array of objects has been unsuccessful.

This is my `repos.rb` class

```
module Github
  class Repos < Base
    attr_accessor :repos

    def initialize(args = [])
      self.repos = parse_repos(args)
    end

    def self.list
      response = Request.get("user/repos")
      Repos.new(response)
    end

    private

    def parse_repos(args = [])
      args.map { |repo| Repo.new(repo) }
    end
  end
end
```

And my `repo.rb` class

```
module Github
  class Repo < Base
    attr_accessor :name,:full_name,:description            
  end
end
```

If you notice I am following the tutorial's style, but I haven't been able to implement it.

With my current implementation, this is the error I am getting in my view

```
  undefined method `each' for #<Github::Repos:0x00007feaadd494d8>
  <% @repos.each do |repo|%>
    <%= repo %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement `each` as the error suggests please read the first paragraph of [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html).

Usually you can just pass this off to an object that is already enumerable (like an `Array` in your case.)

For Example

```
module Github
  class Repos < Base
    include Enumerable

    def self.list
      response = Request.get("user/repos")
      Repos.new(response)
    end

    def initialize(args = [])
      @repos = parse_repos(args)
    end

    def each(&block)
      @repos.each(&block)
    end

    private

    def parse_repos(args = [])
      args.map { |repo| Repo.new(repo) }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I solved the issue. I needed to access the `repos` attribute. See my answer to this question

Comment: I implemented this and makes sense. Thanks, your solution works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my implementation was correct, HOWEVER I needed to access the `repos` attribute like this

```
  <% @repos.repos.each do |repo|%>
    <%= repo.name %>
  <% end %>
```

I don't know why I didn't see this earlier, I guess I was just frustrated

Comment: `attr_accessor :repos` is in general very bad idea; the delegation should be done as shown by @engineersmnky unless this is a one-time-run script.

Comment: What @mudasobwa said. Also even this implementation over exposes `repos` such that `@repos.repos << 12` is functionally possible see my updated suggestion

Comment: Thanks for the tips